# How to get value of selected combo box item from DataGridComboBoxColumn that is created dynamically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Hi i have create a combo box in Data Grid through this code

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn t11 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
            t11.Header = "Select";
             t11.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("[10]");
            ArrayList roow = new ArrayList(); 
            roow.Add("Select");
            roow.Add("Recevied");
            roow.Add("Not Recevied");
            t11.ItemsSource = roow;
            dataGridview.Columns.Add(t11);
```

and the xml code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  />
```

on combo box value selected i want to get the selected value of the combo box and update the database as the value in the datagrid row changed

Comment: How are you binding the row data to the DataGrid?

Comment: object [] value = new object[c];   value[10] = roow[1];    rows.Add(value);    dataGridview.ItemsSource = rows;     and the row is an array.